# How to password reset in Laravel 5.4 by e-mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How do I send the password reset link to the users email when they click on password reset button.

I have a form

```
<form action="/company/password/reset/" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s12">

          <input placeholder="Enter your email" id="emails" type="email" class="validate" required name="email">
          <label for="emails">E-mail Address</label>
        </div>   
      </div>
      <p><button type="submit" method="post">SUBMIT</button></p>
    </form>
```

Routes

```
Route::post('/password/company/reset/', 'PasswordResetController@company');
```

And controller

```
public function company($email)
    {
        $company = $request->email;
    Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $company]);
    }
```

It's not working right now, is this the correct way to do it??

I cannot find any tutorial covering reset password in laravel 5.4

I get this error:

> User must implement CanResetPassword interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form's action is `/company/password/reset/`, the route should be defined as

```
Route::post('/password/company/reset/','PasswordResetController@company');
```

The form's input can be retrieved in the controller as following:

```
public function company(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->email;
    ...
```

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords) explicitly says:

> To get started, verify that your `App\User` model implements the  `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword` contract. Of course, the `App\User` model included with the framework already implements this interface, and uses the  `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword` trait to include the methods needed to implement the interface.

Since you have some custom user model, you need to implement this contract in order to use `Password::sendResetLink`

Comment: Thank you. But how do I send the password reset link.

Comment: Password::sendResetLink($company->email); Apparently this does not work, is there a method like this to send a reset link?

Comment: Please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords There is a number of conditions to meet to make it working. I'd recommend to check logs and update the question with the relevant error messages. There are too many moving parts to make an educated guess. The user may not exists, email transport may be misconfigured etc.

Comment: I get this error - User must implement CanResetPassword interface.

Comment: Dear @ChrisMkp, I have updated your question for now, but you really should do it yourself. See updated answer how to resolve the problem.

Comment: I did follow the documentation , and added those traits in my model, but doesn't work

Comment: Then you must have missed something. Without adding relevant code to the question itself it is hardly possible to tell what exactly.